# MySQL: Selecting all fields based on data in particular field

Tags: mysql, select

I don't know enough to know how to search for this so I'll just throw it out there:

```
| Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 |
+=========+=========+=========+
|   001   |    a    |   xxx   |
|   002   |    c    |   xxx   |
|   003   |    b    |   xxx   |
|   001   |    b    |   xxx   |
|   001   |    c    |   xxx   |
|   002   |    b    |   xxx   |
+=========+=========+=========+
```

I need to check `Field 2` primarily. If `Field 2` ever equals "a", then I need to get the `Field 1` entry from that row and then select all rows that share that particular `Field 1` entry.

I don't really know how to put it into words but an example output based on the table above would be:

```
| Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 |
+=========+=========+=========+
|   001   |    a    |   xxx   |
|   001   |    b    |   xxx   |
|   001   |    c    |   xxx   |
+=========+=========+=========+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourtable.Field1 IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT Field1
   FROM yourtable
   WHERE Field2 = 'a'
) AS childquery
```

the subquery gets all the Field1 records where Field2 is A, then the outer query fetches the entire records that have the matching Field1.

Comment: I don't understand the `AS childquery` part but that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: the `AS childquery` part is unnecessary

Comment: in this case, yeah, uncessary. I just slapped it in by force of habit since I was doing a subquery.

Answer (score 2):

You want to join your table to itself.

```
SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2, t1.field3
FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.field1 = t2.field1
WHERE t2.field2 = 'a'
```

This pulls all records that have `a` in field2 and pulls the columns you show in your example.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51cc9/8)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by simple IN query :

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 AS A 
WHERE FIELD1 IN 
(
 SELECT FIELD1
 FROM TABLE1
 WHERE FIELD2 = 'a'
)
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51cc9/4)